# when to use "imminent" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I was looking for examples of using "imminent" on the web, most of the examples I found was related to attacks and wars.. like, a war is imminent, so I wonder if this word can be used in other settings like these:
- The issuance of the law is imminent.
- the wedding is imminent.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that many dictionary definitions of 'imminent' seem to involve wars or disasters of some kind, and the word is especially used about unpleasant events, but the adjective can be used about anything that is about to happen.

> imminent
>
> adjective UK ​ C2 coming or likely to happen very soon:
>
> imminent disaster/danger A strike is imminent.
>
> More examples
>
> For a man in imminent danger of losing his job, he appeared quite
>   unruffled.
>
> Her remarks were intended to scotch rumours of an imminent election
>   date.
>
> He announced the imminent arrival of a messianic leader.
>
> He gave a dire warning that an earthquake was imminent.
>
> He warned that an enemy missile attack was imminent.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/imminent)

> When the Secret Service arrived, everyone knew the president’s arrival
>   was imminent.
>
> Although the basketball team’s manager has discussed making the star
>   player an offer, no decision is imminent because of the hiring freeze.

[WordInaSentence](https://wordsinasentence.com/imminent-in-a-sentence/)

> The birth of her child was imminent, if not past due.
>
> There was no luggage standing by to indicate an imminent departure.
>
> His success was imminent, and it was thought his appointment as chief
>   minister was assured.

[YourDictionary](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/imminent)